# get image from mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql, database, image, get

after long time i saved my image in mysql field now i want to get this image and show it on my page, this is my php code

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    session_start();
    include('includes/connect.php');
    include('includes/phpCodes.php');

    $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE id='$id' ";
    $image = mysql_query($query);
    $image = mysql_fetch_assoc($image);     

    function showNews(){
        echo '

            <img src=$image class="newsImage">
            <h1><p class="subjecTitle">هنا العنوان</p></h1> 
                <div class="newsContent">
                    hihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihi
                </div>
        ';
    }
?>
```

but nothing happened just show me a broken image, sorry for my bad englsih

Comment: May you please provide more info (*table structure*, *table sample data*)?

Comment: Wrap the `src` in single quotes and go into the `$image`. `mysql_fetch_assoc` will return an array, so you need to do something like `$image = $image['column_name']`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mysql_fetch_assoc()` returns an associative array. You need to tell it which column you are looking for. You also have `$image` wrapped in a literal string. PHP will not substitute variables inside a literal string `'$string'` but will for `"$string"`.

Something like this should work:

```
 echo '<img src="'.$image['columnName'].'" class="newsImage">';
 echo '<h1><p class="subjecTitle">هنا العنوان</p></h1> 
                <div class="newsContent">
                    hihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihihi
                </div>';
```